# How can I find the current date in intel x86 Assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86

I need to find the find the current date in binary for Intel x86 Assembly on Windows. I'm allowed to use Windows procedures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is technically "Windows" (and indeed only works in Windows' emulated DOS environment aka NTVDM, as confirmed by Greg Hewgill), but you could use **INT $21, with $2A in AH**, as this **DOS function** will return the date.  See this [**link**](http://ip-tietgennet.tietgen.dk/staff/mlha/PC/Prog/asm/int/21/index.htm#2A) for more info

Comment: Unfortunately, that will not work in a Win32 environment, only in the emulated DOS environment (NTVDM).

Comment: @Greg H, good point!  +1 for your answer.  I was "lazy" and didn't want to explain the details about binding to Win32, calling conventions etc.

Comment: Actually, this will work in windows, as long as it's not Windows 7.  For that, you'd want to download and install DOSBox (http://www.dosbox.com/).

Comment: Emulations don't matter, otherwise I suggest UAE :-)

Answer (score 6):

If you're allowed to use Win32 functions, then the answer to this would be the same as the answer to "How can I find the current date in C on Windows?" For this, look up the GetSystemTime and SystemTimeToFileTime functions (hey neat, there's even a GetSystemTimeAsFileTime function now! (since Windows 2000)).

Answer (score 2):

GetSystemTime() returns GMT (also known as UTC); for the time that the user sees use GetLocalTime().

To know the exact assembly code, write a call in C, compile with /FA (assuming Microsoft compiler) and snag the calling sequence from the listing file. Might help if you're unsure of the calling convention or how to refer to an external function name in assembly.

Answer (score 1):

**int 20h** and **int 21h** are used to call DOS routines. These can be called either in the virtual mode as supported by 32bit Windows, or in *real mode*, which is when you run with DOS as your actual OS and never enter protected (32 bit) mode. Note that 64 bit processors dropped support for the virtual mode, so you can't use this with a 64 bit chip at all.

For a list of these, check out [Ralf Brown's Interrupt List](http://ctyme.com/rbrown.htm), which is a really comprehensive guide to this now outdated interface.

On Linux, and probably other *nixes, there is a "syscall" interface on **int 80h**. However, all of these can be called via C calling conventions, as well, which is better documented. Check [the Linux source tree](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl) for a number -> name mapping, and run the  `man syscall_name` command for documentation of the equivalent C function's man page. I suppose the arguments are ordered the same way for either calling convention. (I have verified this for a few syscalls.)

The **int 80h** calling convention (for *nix) is documented here: [int80h.org](http://www.int80h.org/bsdasm/#system-calls)